# Hyperref related problem

Tags: hyperref

This minimal working example is not working if `hyperref` is in the preamble. Why is that? Everything else is working fine.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.7,0.8,0.9}
\makeatletter\newenvironment{bluebox}{
   \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
   \colorbox{myblue}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}
}\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thepage}[1]{\centerline{\arabic{page} of 3}}
\centerline{\LARGE{\bf{CURRICULUM VITAE}}}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{bluebox}
{\bf CONTACT}
\end{bluebox}

\end{document}
```

It says:

> ! Argument of \HyPL@CheckThePage has an extra }.  
>                   \par  l.20 \end{document}

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thepage}[1]{...}` → bad idea , your `\thepage macro expects an argument, getting none and is screwing up many things, amongst `\centering` and  the completely outdated `\bf` macro, as well as `\LARGE` does not have an argument

Comment: Damn, I forgot to remove the backticks ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\renewcommand{\thepage}[1]{}` screws up both `hyperref` by expecting an argument now for `\thepage`  as well as the typesetting and the links.

You can use the `lastpage` and `\pageref*{LastPage}` in order to achieve `1 of 10000` etc.

Don't use `\bf` -- it is outdated -- either use `\bfseries` as a font switch or the limiting version `\textbf`. Alsoe `\LARGE` does not have an an argument. Also drop `\centerline`.

I've replaced the weird `\thepage` setting with `fancyhdr` `\fancyfoot[C]{...}` and the blue color box with `tcolorbox` settings.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.7,0.8,0.9}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref*{LastPage}}

\newtcolorbox{bluebox}[1][]{enhanced, sharp corners, frame hidden,colback=myblue,halign=left,boxsep=0pt,fontupper=\bfseries,left=0pt, #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \LARGE \bfseries CURRICULUM VITAE
\end{center}

\begin{bluebox}
\bfseries CONTACT
\end{bluebox}

\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Im sorry, I was hoping I could accept both answers.

Comment: @Aleksander: Concerning the spacings: Use `top=0pt,bottom=0pt` in the `\newtcolorbox` options

Comment: Not the day for backticks!  There's still an unmatched one in your answer (before '\centering').

Comment: @LSpice: Oh, thanks for notifying me. I just corrected the error

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is your redefinition of `\thepage` - it is used by a number packages for auxiliary purposes. The following code replicates your behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thepage}[1]{\centerline{\arabic{page} of 3}}

Random text.

\end{document}
```

Specifically, [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) makes links to the start of the document which requires the use of `\thepage`. Your `\thepage` is not just the page number, but also some formatting and additional text.

Instead, use [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to set your header like so (a suggestion):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

Random text.

\end{document}
```

Note the use of [`lastpage`](//ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) that automatically sets a `\label` (called `LastPage`) for the last page of the document, which we use in the footer to reference it's page. That way you can change the "Page X of Y" dynamically.